# Setting data for type array- RestAssured Post Method

Tags: java, pojo, rest-assured

I am trying to create a pay load for this body and will do a POST.

```
{
    "location": {
        "lat": -38.383494,
        "lng": 33.427362
    },
    "accuracy": 50,
    "name": "Frontline house Seattle",
    "phone_number": "(1) 952 893 3937",
    "address": "29, side layout, cohen 09",
    "types": [
        "shoe park",
        "shop"
    ],
    "website": "http://google.com",
    "language": "French-EN"
}
```

These are the 3 classes I have created

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Payload {
    private Location location;
    private int accuracy;
    private String name;
    private String phone_number;
    private String address;
    private List<Types> types;
    private String website;
    private String language;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Location {
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
}

@Setter
@Getter
public class Types {
    private String zero;
    private String one;
}
```

This below will be will be use to do the post

```
 @Test
    public void createAddress(){
        Location location = new Location(); // Location Class
        location.setLat(-38.383494);
        location.setLng(33.427362);

       Types[] type = new Types[2]; // Type Class


        Payload payload = new Payload();
        payload.setLocation(location); // This is how we will set the Location type class in Payload
        payload.setAccuracy(50);
        payload.setName("Frontline house");
        payload.setPhone_number("(1) 952 893 3937");
        payload.setAddress("29, side layout, cohen 09");
        payload.setTypes();

}
```

**Problem:**  I am not sure how do I set value for Types to create this payload.I also have a feeling I have declared Types incorrectly. In that class I have declared 2 String variables.

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a seperate class for types, since it's a list just declare it as a list of strings

`@Setter
@Getter
private List<String> types;`

The getters and setters for these would be

`public List<String> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }
    public void setTypes(List<String> types) {
        this.types = types;
    }`

In your test

```
List<String> myList =new ArrayList<String>();
    myList.add("shoe park");
    myList.add("shop");

    payload.setTypes(myList);
```